# Java ScheduledExecutorService executes only once

Tags: java, android, timer, concurrency, scheduling

I'm new to Java and trying to make an Android APP that periodically reads some info from my Ubidots variable.

After some research online i managed to find this way of doing it..

The problem is that it only executes once. After the first iteration it never goes through the syncTimer again.

```
        Runnable syncTimer = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ubi.execute(0);

            if (!syncComplete)
            {
                System.out.println("Sync not completed. We'll wait");

                while (!syncComplete)
                {
                    //wait.
                }
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try
                    {
                        syncComplete(tempValue, g_tempVal.toString());
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        System.err.println("error in executing. It will no longer be run!");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }

                }
            });

        }
    };

    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(syncTimer, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This is my code, any help with this issue ? I'm all out of ideas what to search on google to find a way of solving it.

I've never programmed in Java/Android, only used other languages.

syncComplete is a boolean set after an AsyncTask which connects to Ubidots and retrieves variables.

```
   public class ApiUbidots extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {
    private final String API_KEY = "key";
    private final String VARIABLE_ID = "var";

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(API_KEY);
        Variable temperature = apiClient.getVariable(VARIABLE_ID);
        if (params[0] == 0)
        {
            g_tempVal = temperature.getValues()[0].getValue();
            syncComplete = true;
        }
        if (params[0] == 1)
        {
            //implement write function
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your while runs forever. The thread can't even be reused since you blocked it.

Comment: no, it doesn't, I said in the description that i'm setting it to true once the data from Ubidots is received... I've checked that, it's not the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes to `syncComplete`are not visible to your thread if they are made by another thread. You need to declare your `syncComplete` variable as volatile, like this:

`public volatile boolean syncComplete=false;`

> Using volatile variables reduces the risk of memory consistency errors, because any write to a volatile variable establishes a happens-before relationship with subsequent reads of that same variable. This means that changes to a volatile variable are always visible to other threads.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html

Also, active waiting by spinning in a while loop is bad practice. Try locking instead.

Comment: I'll research a bit about locking and see if I can understand how to use it. Meanwhile... this didn't fix it. the problem is not with the syncComplete variable, it doesn't even start the second iteration after the 2 seconds wait time. After executing the first one it just... does nothing, it doesn't get stuck in that while loop.